# Over query limit and maximum call stack size

Tags: javascript, limit, settimeout, google-places-api, callstack

Here I create a code with google map, google places, routebox library to show directions beetween two locations and to show object near direction (10,20,30 miles) with google places.

Here is the demo and code: http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/55 but after trying "10mi" distance, from Madrid to Moscow I get this errors:

```
    ...
    ...
    ...


   OVER_QUERY_LIMIT 55:121
    199
    OVER_QUERY_LIMIT 55:121
    OK 55:121
    1268
    OVER_QUERY_LIMIT 55:121
    3
    OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This code:

```
service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
    console.log(status);
    if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
        setTimeout(findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex),10000);
    }else{
        document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds["+searchIndex+"] returns "+results.length+" results<br>";

        for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
            var marker = createMarker(result);
        }
        if (++searchIndex < boxes.length) 
            setTimeout(findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex),10000);
    }
  });
```

This code stop searching in boxes[14]. Why?

I pt in code `setTimeot` with 10s before call next box?

What is the really problem here?

Comment: What is:     Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
, and why I get Over query limit when I pt setTimeot with 10s ... i think that script workmuch faster ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wrap the call of `findPlaces` into a function, otherwise the function will be called immediately and not with the desired delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex);},10000);
```